# nodejs deconstruction of require

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to deconstruct a require assignment of express along with importing the main export itself:

```
const express, {static: expressStatic, json, urlencoded} = require("express");
```

However it fails:

```
const express, {static: expressStatic, json, urlencoded} = require("express");
      ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: That's the same as `cont express; const {…} = require(…);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot perform this in one line.

```
const express = require("express");
const {static: expressStatic, json, urlencoded} = express;
```

[Destructure in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in a single statement, you can use

```
const express = require("express"), {static: expressStatic, json, urlencoded} = express;
```